# Django object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, django-models

I have a query on foreign key field that is returning the following error.

```
'Category' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Here is my query:

```
p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
categories = p.categories.all()
```

Based on these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,  unique=True, help_text='Unique value from product page URL, created from name')
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
```

I understand the issue is a result of the foreign key referencing only one model; however, when I try to run:

```
categories = p.categories
```

I return the following error:

```
'Category' object is not iterable
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: The way that you lay down the models allows you to only relate a single category to each product, you probably looking for m2m relation here. Try to do more reading in django docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different approach for your relationships. The way I see your code you should have a ManytoMany relationship since one product may belongs to N categories and one category may have N products attached to it.

Check this [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related)

Anyway try to change this in your `Product` model:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True)
```